# Ajax Call from a button in a table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Dear Programmers 
 I have got a block of code which is retrieved through an Ajax call. First off, take a look at that piece:

```
$output .= '</td><td class="td-align">'.$employees["fullname"].'</td>
        <td class="td-align">'.$employees["faname"].'</td>
        <td class="td-align ">'.$employees["sid"].'</td>
        <td class="td-align ">'.$employees["nid"].'</td>
        <td class="td-align"><button type="button" name="update" id="'.$employees["id"].'" class="buttons edit-button"><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> insert </button></td>  
       </tr>
     ';
```

This block is printed within a div with the id 'found_employees'. As you can guess here I am searching the employees. The found employees are listed in the table, as obvious in this block of code. The next step I haven't been able to find a solution for. As you can see there is a button at the latest td. On this button click, I want to copy the selected employee into another div with the id 'employees_to_be_registered'. This div is actually a form which will register the searched employees in one special department. The scenario will be like this: On button clicked, I want the information of the employee to be copied into an input tag to be processed in the form. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to set a span around the employee information, like:

```
    <td class="td-align"><span id='eFullname'>'.$employees["fullname"].'</span></td>
    <td class="td-align"><span id='eFanme'>'.$employees["faname"].'</span></td>
    <td class="td-align "><span id='eSid'>'.$employees["sid"].'</span></td>
    <td class="td-align "><span id='eNid'>'.$employees["nid"].'</span></td>
    <td class="td-align">
        <button type="button" name="update" id="'.$employees["id"].'" class="buttons edit-button">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> insert
        </button>
    </td>
```

then you are able to get text text content out of it with e.g. document.getElementById("eFullname").textContent and insert it into another input from type text with

```
<input type="text" id="anotherTextfield" />

document.getElementById("anotherTextfield").value=document.getElementById("eFullname").textContent
```

Comment: A very good suggestion in the first place. Now two question raises: One, how can I do the process with an Ajax call. then, I might get many employees, on click event, how can I distinguish which ID is being sent??

Comment: I dont really understand your first question. the ajax call is the thing which is already done. we are talking the steps after ajax call?!
second question: so I believe you have multiple datasets/rows. so you generate multiple id's with a number. use the onclick event in the button to execute a function and in the parameter, you can insert your row id

Comment: Many thanks for your patience dear DubZ. I am actually going to call another Ajax command. Look at this part: "<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$employees["id"].'" class="buttons edit-button">" The id here is the id of one employee as retrieved from database. I have set it as the id of the button, which I think is not a good practice here in my case. In my second Ajax call, at first, it seems that I should guess the id to call it, which is impossible. The scenario is, I want this button, to be with an sign or id, for example, 'add_employee', and with a value, that is the...

Comment: id of the employee in the database. In this case I can call it. Can you plz show me how can I do this. Suppose that I am going to send that employee id to another page on button click.

Comment: you can use the onclick event on your button like onclick="ajaxFunction(employeeId)" and call a function you defined before where you execute your ajax request and pass the employeeid to the ajax function.
for this you also need to modify your id's from the span element I posted in my first post. you have to extend with the employeeid, like id="eFullname1"

Answer (score 0):

**"How can I call <<< id="'.$employees["id"] >>> and send the ID to the other page to be processed?"**

This code can help to answer that part of the question:

```html
"<td>
  <a href='employeed_to_be_registered.php?id=".$employees["id"]."'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>View</button>
  </a>
</td>"
```

This will redirect to the designated page with id in the URL.

Comment: I have not answered your question, let me know if you want to stick with your idea.

Comment: Question is I don't know how to do that with an Ajax call. Let's forget about the second part of the question. How can I process the id alone. Within Ajax block, how can I call <<< id="'.$employees["id"] >>> and send the ID to the other page to be processed?? The problem is its in a table and not in an input tag, that's why I am stuck what to do.

Comment: Thanks dear Bundhoo Nadeem, I actually wanted to avoid sending get requests, and I wanted to do the process with an Ajax call. I actually did Dubz's suggestion (that is defining an onClick"" for the button itself and call the Jquery function from there directly.) And its working. Thanks once again.